Result of "findfrequency" depends on Signal to Noise
I tried forecast::findfrequency with some test signals with various noise added to the clean sinusoid. Example:
        signal1=signal0+a*rnorm(length(t),0,b)
        result =findfrequency(signal1)    ```
examples:
a=0, b=0.4; result=1
a= 1, b=0.4; result = 5
a= 0.1, b= 0.4; result =3
a=0.5, b= 0.1; result = 3
Can anybody tell me, what I made wrong?
Thank You



